# Does anyone know what this waxy coating on a post card is called?

Tags: print-design, print-production, paper

I am trying to ask a print broker for a quote on some postcards but I don't know what the name of this coating is. This postcard gets attached to a lanyard and the coating looks great and avoids it tearing at the hole punch. I did a scan so you can see the finish.

[image: Scan of Waxy Coating]

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: A printer friend has just suggested that it is a matte laminate. Once I get the postcards I will update if it was correct.

Comment: When I look at the area where the hole is it seems like there was a lot of stress on that area and it helped. Of course the paper gsm is around 240 so that is the main reason for the durability. The laminate also helps the image stay smooth instead of bending when its worn all day and handled frequently.

Comment: That's typically laminated. A separate process from printing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is one of two cellophane lamination applied after print, I comes in a film roll format, in matte and glossy, the matte one is the one that has that waxy feel to it.